# Multiple boot: Windows-10 along Linux?

Tags: windows, grub2, boot-loader

On a computer running for the long term **Linux Mint 17** Xfce (ubuntu 14.04) along **Windows 7** I have created **another two separate partitions** with the purpose of installing for the short term other systems for testing purposes. So, I have the intention of keeping an eye on the development of certain distributions... e.g. Elementary OS, Bodhi Linux, Manjaro, and other Linux builds, but also Windows 10 ("Technical Preview").

As expected, installing Windows 10 on one of these two supplementary partitions has removed the boot list (grub) installed by the latest Linux ; that is, the computer booted directly into Windows 10, with no option to boot in Windows 7 or any of the Linux systems.

I have restored the grub with `grub-repair` tool - [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) - with the result that on boot I can choose between the Linux OS-es and Windows 7, while Windows 10 is not present in the list.

Why is that? -- and: Can it be added to the boot list in grub?

I want to take a look at Windows 10 Technical Preview for a while, but keeping access at the same time to my main boot options Linux/Win7. Is that possible?

---

EDIT in reply to comment:

`sudo update-grub` gives:

```
 ~ $ sudo update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found theme: /boot/grub/themes/Grau/theme.txt
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-45-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-45-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic
  No volume groups found
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda2
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda4
Found Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (14.04) on /dev/sda6
done
```

What is accessible are in fact all systems: Mint, Voyager (a Xubuntu-based distro) and Windows 7, but no Windows 10.

Comment: Did you try `sudo update-grub` ?

Comment: @Muhammad - no Win10 found, please see edit in Q

Comment: @Muhammad - thanks to your comment I got it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever the reason,  what grub sees as `Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda2` is in fact Windows 10 loader.

To change the name one can use [`grub-customizer`](https://launchpad.net/~danielrichter2007/+archive/ubuntu/grub-customizer) ([click](https://launchpad.net/~danielrichter2007/+archive/ubuntu/grub-customizer)) in Linux.

Answer (score 0):

A better answer was given here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/666317/grub2-shows-windows-7-instead-of-windows-10

It involves editing the file in `/usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/20microsoft` to add Windows 10 to the list of OSes recongized by Grub2